Does Visual Studio have a shortcut key to toggle Intellisense off and on?
I'm looking for a quick and easy way to toggle IntelliSence on/off in Visual Studio, as I find it helpful when programming but prefer to have it disabled while learning to better understand the code. Is there a simple method or a shortcut key for this? This question is not language specific.

This answer presumes Visual Studio 2022, and language c++, as you did not provide any specifics, however the answer should still point you in the right direction.
From withing VS application select the menu option Tools->Options
In the Search Options box type "Intelli"
Find the IntelliSense section for the programming language you are using (c++ for example) and untick "Enable inline hints"
